# Ширина div по умолчанию идёт на всю ширину страницы или родителя?

Tags: css, html, width, блок

В теории: "Ширина div по умолчанию идёт на всю ширину страницы. Если div является потомком — то на всю ширину родителя". Но, ведь любой div априори получается потомком body/html. Где же истина?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По умолчанию на ширину родителя, то есть если `<div>` внутри `<body>`, то на его ширину.

Comment: Про это и говорю, что любой div всегда будет потомком body, html. Но, что означает тогда: "ширина блочных элементов по умолчанию идёт на всю ширину страницы" в теории?

Comment: По умолчанию <body> на всю страницу. Ты можешь вставить див2 внутрь див1 и див2 уже будет потомком родителя див1. Обычный DOM, можешь себе представить это как лесенку:)

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Наверное, я некорректно сформулировал вопрос. Т.е. в теории: "Ширина div по умолчанию идёт на всю ширину страницы. Если div является потомком — то на всю ширину родителя". Так какой правильный ответ, div по умолчанию идёт на всю ширину страницы или на всю ширину родителя? Ведь div априори становится потомком. Потомком body/html :)

Comment: Мне кажется у тебя мозги кипят уже. У всех элементов по умолчанию свойство width: auto; это означает, что они принимают значение ширины родителя.

Comment: Просто хочу докопаться до истины. Не зря же в спецификации ширине отведено 10 параграфов.

Comment: Все блочные элементы(в том числе `<div>`) по умолчанию занимают 100% ширины НЕПОСРЕДСТВЕННОГО родителя. Только и всего.

Comment: @ГеннадийЖуров можете скинуть источник? (п.с. здесь http://htmlbook.ru/content/blochnye-elementy написано: "По умолчанию ширина блока вычисляется автоматически и занимает все доступное пространство. Здесь следует оговорить, что под этим подразумевается. Например, если тег <div> в коде документа присутствует один, то он занимает всю свободную ширину окна браузера и ширина блока будет равна 100%. Стоит поместить один тег <div> внутрь другого, как ширина внутреннего тега начинает исчисляться относительно его родителя, т.е. внешнего контейнера."

Comment: Т.е. 1 тег div — то на всю ширину страницы. В этом и загвоздка. Ведь div получает родителя body/html автоматически. Возможно, они не имеют в виду body, а только конкретные дополнительные контейнеры уже внутри body.

Comment: один тег `div` занимает не всю ширину страницы, а всю ширину тега `body` т.е. своего непосредственного родителя. В этом можно убедиться, задав ширину для `body`.

Comment: @ГеннадийЖуров я это знаю, и тестировал локально. Поэтому и вопрос, что в теории говорится, если 1 тег div — то на всю ширину окна браузера и как бы подразумевается, что он не является никаким потомком. Хотя в локальном тесте он автоматически становится потомком body. В общем, спасибо за ответы. Буду разбираться дальше, мб ещё покопаюсь в спецификации. Но, кто-то что-то явно напутал.